# iOS 5.1 (Xcode 4.4) Webpage does not load in my tab bar controller with UIWebViewer

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.4

I'm quite a fresh in Apple AppDevelopment, I have some experience with C# on VS2010 though and I already found some similarities. But I am stuck on some odd malfunction. I'm currently working on a program for iOS 5.1 on Iphone and Ipad. This application should be able to do the following actions:

1. Make a photo with the camera option
2. View the library
3. Browse a webpage
4. Easily upload an image into an HTML form.

These functions are all combined in a tab bar controller.

However after 2 weeks of wrestling in the mud I have been unable to get the webviewer working.

No errors are shown however the webpage that should load (simply google) isn't loading and the screen remains white. I was browsing the internet for some good tutorials to help me figure out how to develop an application doing something like this. (Unfortunatly in vain) I was hoping for someone able to help me with this problem. I'll leave my source code below for inspection.
Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Kind regards 
App.Dev.: TheWolf

P.S.: I'm working with Storyboards in this project.

Code Webapp.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface Webapp : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIWebview *webView;
@end
```

Code Webapp.m

```
#import "Webapp.h"
@interface Webapp ()
@end

@implementation
@synthesize webView = _webview;

-(void) ViewDidLoad
{
  [super.viewDidLoad];
  self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
  [self.webView loadRequest: NSURLRequest resquestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
}

-(void) ViewDidUnload
{
  [super.viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
  return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

Comment: I´ve been busy trying to fix this problem while waiting for an anser. It turned out that I made a mistake in making a relationship within the Nib (.xib) file. I got it fully working with address bar and action buttons now. If anyone requires the code, just give me a howler and I will post it when I can.